# How to search in a row and populate Yes/No value in another row - excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have two columns A and B. Column A has rental property descriptions. I want to search each row containing the word "parking" and return Yes/No in column B

I tried using =IF(SEARCH("parking",A2),"Yes","No") and it did return me a value of "Yes" . But when the word is not found i am getting a #VALUE error instead f a NO.

Is there a way to get Yes/No from search?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SEARCH` will return an error if not found, and when the criteria in an `IF` is an error it will error the whole formula. so, wrap it in `ISNUMBER`, this way if it is an error the `ISNUMBER` will return `FALSE` instead of an error.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("parking",A2)),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Great, It solved my question. Thank you!